# How to convert ErrorCode to String with ASP.NET MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to convert the `ERRORCODE` to String with ASP.NET MVC5,

with ASP.NET MVC3 we can convert the error code to String using this code:

```
// Attempt to register the user
MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
ErrorCodeToString(createStatus);
```

but with ASP.NET MVC5, it shows an error using the `ErrorCodeToString`
because it is undefined.

**Last_EDIT**

HttpStatusCode belong to  Mvc3ToolsUpdateWeb_Default.Models is there any equal namespace with mvc5 ?

::::::::::
this is the error
[image]

Comment: did you try `ErrorCode.ToString`?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, it gave the same error

Comment: thanks for vote down but why???

Comment: The errors are in an enum called `HttpStatusCode` in the `System.Net` namespace.

Comment: @Transcendent i am importing System.net namespace
but still give the same error

Comment: @ElieMA: What error do you get, add to the question, take a snapshot too.

Comment: @Transcendent just a minute please

Comment: @Transcendent see the error please i edited the post

Comment: @ElieMA: but this has nothing to do with my comment, try "System.Net.HttpStatusCode" and then get your error your are after by the code presenting it and convert to string effortlessly since that is an enum

Comment: @Transcendent ,,look Bro , i found that HttpStatusCode doesnt belong to System.net
but to Mvc3ToolsUpdateWeb_Default.Models
is there any equal library with   mvc5 ?

Comment: @ElieMA: I'm writing the answer, check back in a while

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the string value representing the error code using the following method:

```
 public String ErrorCodeToString(int errorCode){
     return ((System.Net.HttpStatusCode)errorCode).ToString();
 }
```

The above method does not need exception handling as no exception will be thrown upon passing bad values. What happens is that in case an index is not available, the input number will be cast to string.

**Additional Information:**

And you can do the opposite using the following approach:

```
public int ErrorToErrorCode(String error){
    try{
        return (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(System.Net.HttpStatusCode), error);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        //Log the exception
        return -1; // or a value indicating the error has occurred
 }
```

Or may use the `Enum.TryParse` instead if you do not like the `try` and `catch`.

For more information regarding the `System.Net.HttpStatusCode` you can refer to the following MSDN topic: [HttpStatusCode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

According to your code you can put this

> ModelState.AddModelError("",
>   ((System.Net.HttpStatusCode)createStatus).ToString());